# Guava cache expires after the first write

Tags: java, guava

I am using Guava [CacheBuilder](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/16.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) and normally I can expire my records after last read or last write:

```
LoadingCache<String, CacheObject> myCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
    .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .build(
        new CacheLoader<String, CacheObject>() {
            public CacheObject load(String cacheKey) {
                return ...
            }
        });
```

But, I need to expire my records after first write. It means if later on, I rewrite that record with a new value:

```
myCache.put(existingCacheKey, newCacheObject);
```

Still I want to expire the record based on first write.

It looks like CacheBuilder does not support it by default. I am wondering if there is a way to make it expire by first write.

Comment: first write and then expire,cache is not for this case?

Comment: @TongChen, do you suggest any other structure to achieve this purpose?

Comment: Sounds like requirement to NOT to use cache.

Comment: @ Arashsoft every time get the value you want. I may not understand the thoughts you really want to express. can you give more information?

Comment: @TongChen, I do not want to recalculate the CacheObject everytime I read it so I need a cache. Also, I might update it sometimes but it should not affect the expiring time.

Comment: You can probably store not the object itself but a holder. The holder would be added once, never overwritten, and expire.

Comment: @yegodm Thank you for the suggestion. Using a wrapper class is a good idea to do not reset expiring time. I will go that way until I find a better structure to support what I need.

Comment: [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine), a Guava cache rewrite, supports a [custom expiration policy](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Eviction#time-based).